# How is an email password change logged in a postfix/dovecot system?

Tags: postfix, logging, dovecot, password

I've got an email user whose email password has been changed in the last day or so, but he doesn't know how it happened.

The system is Debian Stretch postfix/dovecot.

How is such a change in an email password logged in that system?

Comment: What backend is used for passwords? On my postfix+dovecot set ups it is all mysql for users, user passwords, etc.

Comment: Standard Unix user database

Comment: The syslog or pam_unix logging should show when/who changed a user's password.